# How to get next hour's 15th minute of time from given time in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way of getting the next hour's 15th minutes from given time?

For Example

1. if input is `2021-08-26 12:00:37` then output should be `2021-08-26 12:15:00`
2. if input is `2021-08-26 12:30:37` then output should be `2021-08-26 13:15:00`

Comment: I initially thought what @CBroe thought as well which would have made this a bit of an interesting question. However if you just want the next 15th minute of the hour it's a bit trivial. There's 2 possibilities either the time is before the 15th minute of this hour or after and it's trivial to generate the correct time given this

Comment: If the point is to get the date when it will be next 15 minutes (even if now it is 15 minutes and 1 second), this code will do it:

https://3v4l.org/cZYfu

Comment: @moderator - The question is not answered in the linked post. At least not for someone asking such a basic question.

The easiest way is to let DateTime handle the rollover of dates etc.:
```php
$inputDate = new DateTimeImmutable('2021-08-26 12:00:37');

// implying you also want to turn 12:15 into 13:15
$newHour = $inputDate->format('H') + ($inputDate->format('i') >= 15 ? 1 : 0);

$next15th = $inputDate->setTime($newHour, 15, 0);
```
(Would be more readable in an answer but was closed during writing... -.-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub)

It is installed by default in Laravel.

```
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',  '2021-08-26 12:00:37'); 

$newDate = $date->addMinutes(15)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Please share more details. How would this work for the second input string, where way more than 15 minutes should be added?

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the date to a timestamp and then add it the equivalent of 15 minutes in seconds (15 * 60) and then convert it back to a date

Comment: Please share more details. How would this work for the second input string, where way more than 15 minutes should be added?

Comment: @NicoHaase in that case it would not work. When I responded the question was "How to get next 15th minute of time from given time in PHP" which is not the same. My answer not correct anymore

Comment: As far as I see, the two example inputs and the corresponding expected outputs have been in the question since the initial state

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you looking for...

```
$start = '2018-05-21 20:24:45';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+15 minutes',strtotime($start)));
```

Comment: That does not work. For both given sample inputs, your code returns a different result as expected